# Is it possible to do a sort of stage light behind this text?

Tags: css, styling

I am trying to recreate this piece in the image but in CSS, HTML and JavaScript. I would prefer the design to be purely CSS. The part I need to recreate is that slight upwards lighting effect and the bottom border.

Can someone please help me out?

**[Lighting Effect + Border]**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you can use a [linear gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Let's see the html and css you have so far.

Comment: Sorry but you are expected to put some effort in yourself. Stack Overflow is NOT a code writing service. Questions along the line of "Here is something cool..... how do I do it?" are not well received. Try more for "Here is something cool.... here's what I tried and here is how I failed. What did I do wrong?". The border is easy, any CSS tutorial will show you how to set `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do something like this..

**HTML**

```
<div class="stage">
    <h1>Trending Movies</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stage{
  // This is just a random gradient not the one you have shown
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
  height: // your height;
  width: // your width
}
.stage h1{
    font-size: // your font size
    text-align: center;
    padding: // your padding
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

this will get you started on the desired effect, you can use this tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create your gradient and generate the css